# How to deal with a mistake in a question after answers were provided?

Tags: discussion

I asked [How to theoretically calculate the maximum acceleration?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/11407/how-to-theoretically-calculate-the-maximum-acceleration) but I noticed that I made a mistake in the formula.

The question (body, not title) was only about one aspect, which has been answered properly, but now a second one arose.

How should I handle the mistake and the already posted (good) answer?

Answer (score 3):

IIWY, I would just edit the question (using the `edit` link beneath your post, and leave a comment (mentioning the update) for the person who answered (i.e. Tom), by addressing them, using their username and preceding it with the `@` symbol (or, easier still, just leave a comment under their answer).

Tom will then be able to update his answer, so that both question and answer remain in-sync.

There is an edit history anyway (again, accessible via the `edited` link beneath the post), if that is your concern, so all changes can be tracked and viewed (and rolled back to, if need be) at a later date.

However, Tom appears to have picked up your error already, and left you a comment.

Comment: I think this is salient advice.